# How can I convert this JSON file to a specific pandas dataframe layout?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file that looks like so:

```
data
```

```
[{'timestamp': '2013-04-30T00:00:00.000Z',
  'searchInterval': '2880',
  'btcDominance': 94.3854,
  'ethDominance': 0,
  'quote': [{'name': 'USD',
    'timestamp': '2013-04-30T00:00:00.000Z',
    'totalMarketCap': 1686950016.0,
    'totalVolume24H': 0.0,
    'totalVolume24HReported': 0.0,
    'altcoinVolume24H': 0.0,
    'altcoinVolume24HReported': 0.0,
    'altcoinMarketCap': 94716304.0,
    'originalScore': '1367280120'}],
  'score': 1367280000000.0},
 {'timestamp': '2013-05-02T00:00:00.000Z',
  'searchInterval': '2880',
  'btcDominance': 94.0775,
  'ethDominance': 0,
  'quote': [{'name': 'USD',
    'timestamp': '2013-05-02T00:00:00.000Z',
    'totalMarketCap': 1333880064.0,
    'totalVolume24H': 0.0,
    'totalVolume24HReported': 0.0,
    'altcoinVolume24H': 0.0,
    'altcoinVolume24HReported': 0.0,
    'altcoinMarketCap': 78998704.0,
    'originalScore': '1367452920'}],
  'score': 1367452800000.0},
...
...
```

How can I sort through this data to create a dataframe that looks like so:

```
print(df)
```

```
                   timestamp    totalMarketCap
0   2013-04-30T00:00:00.000Z      1686950016.0
...                      ...               ...
```

Hope this example helps! And I appreciate your help!

Comment: So you want the `timestamp` and  `totalMarketCap` from with in`quote`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris Correct!

Comment: use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)  - `df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'quote')[['timestamp', 'totalMarketCap']]` You can remove the `[['timestamp', 'totalMarketCap']]` if you want all the columns in `quote`